# Dynamically load a table using javascript

Tags: performance

I want to load the table dynamically as soon as the page loads.i have tried the following code , but it is not showing 2nd column values found out in javascript.plz help me out.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text\javascript">
var brw=navigator.appCodeName;
var bw=navigator.appName;
var vrs=navigator.appVersion;
var plt=navigator.platform;
document.getElementById('r1').innerHTML = ' '+brw;
document.getElementById('r2').innerHTML = ' '+bw;
document.getElementById('r3').innerHTML = ' '+vrs;
document.getElementById('r4').innerHTML = ' '+plt;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr><td>Browser code </td><td><div id='r1'></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Browser </td><td><div id='r2'></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Browser Version </td><td><div id='r3'></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Platform </td><td><div id='r4'></div></td></tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything seems fine, you can check the fiddle. Are you sure you don't have another HTML element with the id="r2"? http://jsfiddle.net/BPSFL/

Comment: i didnt get u . no i dont have another html element

Answer (score 0):

Your table should be like :

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Browser code</th>
    <th>Browser</th>
    <th>Browser version</th>
    <th>Platform</th>      
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><div id='r1'></div></td>
     <td><div id='r2'></div></td>
     <td><div id='r3'></div></td>
     <td><div id='r4'></div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This way your table heads are set at top in `<thead>` balise, then you can add rows in `<tbody>` balise.

Comment: I want 'Browser code' part and '<div>' part both in same row but in separate columns.the way you told both of them will be in separate rows.

Comment: Indeed, I assumed the first part was the table header. You can do the same without the <thead> part, and put 2 divs inside each <td></td>

Comment: Why do we need 2 divs inside each <td></td>.i want them in separate rows

Comment: What you're trying to do is weird. I think you haven't realy understood the table concept.

Comment: It will be hard to explain it here. Read this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp Good luck !

Answer (score -1):

Just put your Javascript code at the end of your page.